# this is window inside the function of a class

Tags: javascript, class, this, prototype

I have some code here.
I am aware that this reference wont be carried in anonymous functions.
But here, even when using a function of an object, the this inside that is window.

```js
var MyClass = function (div) {

    this.array = [];
};

MyClass.prototype = {
  addToArray: function (elem) {
    this.array.push(elem);
  },
  processAndAdd: function(elemArray){
    elemArray.forEach(this.addToArray);
  }
}

var myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.processAndAdd([1, 2, 3]);
console.log('test');
```

Error: Line: this.array.push(elem);

push of undefined.

On inspection, the this here is window Object

I want to know why this is window here, and how to restructure my code to properly handle this.

Comment: When you pass the function reference to `forEach`, it loses its `this`, as it's no longer being called on the `this` (ie: myObj). The `.forEach()` method allows you to specify the this for the callback: `.forEach(this.addToArray, this)`

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `this` object is no more `MyClass` constructor after you pass the callback function body as callback to `forEach`. Bind the function body with the current `this` context and your code should work.

```
    var MyClass = function (div) {
    
        this.array = [];
    };
    
    MyClass.prototype = {
      addToArray: function (elem) {
        this.array.push(elem);
      },
      processAndAdd: function(elemArray){
        elemArray.forEach(this.addToArray.bind(this));
      }
    }
    
    var myObj = new MyClass();
    myObj.processAndAdd([1, 2, 3]);
    console.log('test');
```

Comment: The issue with bind is that it will create a new function right? This part of the code will be called many times, and I want it to be as effecient as possible. 
I think that Nick's comment might be a better suit for me. I can pass the context to foreach.